# Fully programmatically rename columns in R with dplyr

Tags: r, pandas, dataframe

I have sensor data, for several different sensor types, in many dataframes. I need to perform inner_joins on the dataframes so that I end up with one dataframe. The column names of the dataframes for a given sensor type are identical, e.g.

```
> z501h001

  timeBgn soilTempMean soilTempVar
1 01:00:00     100        4
2 01:30:00     112        6
3 02:00:00     111        6

> z501h002

timeBgn soilTempMean soilTempVar
1 01:00:00     120        4
2 01:30:00     122        6
3 02:00:00     121        5
```

except there are way more columns.  The column names are different for different types of sensors (they all have `timeBgn` in common) .

I need (in R) a flexible way to rename the columns (so I can tell which column corresponds to which sensor) based on adding a suffix to the existing column names for all columns except timeBgn (which is the common column by which the inner_join will be done).

Here is the Python / Pandas equivalent of what I am trying to do:

```
def rename_cols_by_sensor(df, sensor_name):
    cols = df.columns
    new_cols = [f'{c}_{sensor_name}' if c!='timeBgn' else c for c in cols] 
    df.columns = new_cols
```

I found most of a solution here:
[programmatically rename columns in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50749875/programmatically-rename-columns-in-dplyr#50750148)

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to make the cnames vector programmatically.  I do not want to hard-code all of the myriad column names. As an example for `z501h001` it would need to look like

```
cnames <- c('soilTempMean' = 'soilTempMean_z501h001', 'soilTempVar' = 'soilTempVar_z501h001')
```

the suffix (in the example: _z501h001) can be passed to the function so there is no need to discuss obtaining it here. The original names are easily obtained using `names(df)`.  All I need to know is how to put them together in this `c("character" = "other_character")` format.

I have tried:

```
rename_by_loc <- function(df, loc) {
    old_names <- names(df)
    new_names <- c()
    loc = z501h001
    for (name in old_names) {
        if (name != "timeBgn") { 
            new_names <- c(new_names, paste(name, paste(name, loc, sep="_"), sep = " = ") )
        }
    }
    return(new_names)
}
```

but that gives me names like `"soilTempMean = soilTempMean_z501h001"`

I need the = to be outside of the character strings. I have tried a few other things. None have been successful.

This problem is trivial using Pandas which makes me think I am missing something about column renaming in R.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `mget` to get all the values of the objects with the pattern for object names starts with 'z' followed by 3 digits, 'h', and then 3 digits in a `list`, then use `imap` to loop over the `list` and `rename` all those columns except 'timeBgn' by concatenating (`str_c`) the original column with the object name

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
out <- mget(ls(pattern = "^z\\d{3}h\\d{3}$")) %>%
    imap(~  {
             nm1 <- .y
             .x %>%
                rename_with(~ str_c(., "_", nm1), -timeBgn)
           })
```

The output will be a `list`.  If we need to change the column name in the original object (not recommended), use `list2env`

```
list2env(out, .GlobalEnv)
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
v1 <- ls(pattern = "^z\\d{3}h\\d{3}$")
for(v in v1) {
  tmp <- get(v)
  i1 <- names(tmp) != 'timeBgn'
  names(tmp)[i1] <- paste0(names(tmp)[i1], '_', v)
  assign(v, tmp)
}
```